# ASP NET Core 6 MVC Slow page loading

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to upgrade an old ASP .NET project from Framework 4.5 to Core .NET 6.

Going well so far, but I noticed the page loading was way longer than before. I thought it may come from Entity Framework, but even simple pages were slow.

So I created a new project from the ASP .NET CORE 6 sample and noticed the same problem.

When I navigate between the default "Home" and "Privacy" pages, it takes around 2 seconds to load (not only the first time). Using Chrome and Firefox's inspectors, the pending is the slow part.

I don't think this is normal, is it an issue with the framework or my setup ?

For information, I tried in debug and release mode same problem. But when I ran with the profiler, everything was perfectly fast !

Any ideas on what's happening ?

Comment: Could it not be your machine/ server? Have you checked Task Manager on your machine?

Comment: I am running it on my local machine with a i7-10870H CPU and 32Gb of RAM on a SSD. My memory usage doesn't exceed 60% and CPU < 20% usage.

I don't think it comes from here. But i'll try to publish the sample on a test server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please upgrade your vs2022 to the latest version， then test again.